# Mock testing in Go

Tags: go

Mock testing in golang

In this test case, the NewSocket function is used to create an HTTP client with the mock transport. A GET request is made to "/some/path", and the response status code and body content are asserted to ensure they match the expected values based on the mock response.

```
package socket_test

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    "your/package/path/socket"
)

type MockTransport struct {
    Response *http.Response
    Error    error
}

func (m *MockTransport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return m.Response, m.Error
}
type MockTransport struct {
    Response *http.Response
    Error    error
}
```

Comment: what i sthe question and what is te problem that you are facing?? all I see above are statements that you have made.

Answer (score 1):

```
package socket_test

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    "your/package/path/socket"
)

type MockTransport struct {
    Response *http.Response
    Error    error
}

func (m *MockTransport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return m.Response, m.Error
}

func TestSocketRequest(t *testing.T) {
    // Create a mock response and transport for a successful case
    mockResponse := &http.Response{
        StatusCode: http.StatusOK,
        Body:       httptest.NewBodyString("Mock response"),
    }
    mockTransport := &MockTransport{
        Response: mockResponse,
        Error:    nil,
    }

    // Override http.DefaultTransport with the mock transport
    originalTransport := http.DefaultTransport
    defer func() {
        http.DefaultTransport = originalTransport
    }()
    http.DefaultTransport = mockTransport

    // Call the NewSocket function to create a client with the mock transport
    client := socket.NewSocket("/path/to/socket")

    // Make a request using the client
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/some/path", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Error creating request: %v", err)
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Error making request: %v", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Assert the response status code and body content
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("Expected status code %d, but got: %d", http.StatusOK, resp.StatusCode)
    }

    expectedBody := "Mock response"
    actualBody, _ := httptest.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if string(actualBody) != expectedBody {
        t.Errorf("Expected body %q, but got: %q", expectedBody, string(actualBody))
    }
}
```